# Is there a difference between 1 and 2 (complexity time or clean code better)?

Tags: python

***1:***

```
it_courses = {'CS': ('Discrete Structures (2)', 'Compiler Construction', 'Theory of computation'), 'SE': (
    'Software Analysis and Design', 'Project management', 'Advanced Internet Computing')}

def register_courses(it_courses, dep_acronym):
    if dep_acronym == 'CS':
        for index in it_courses['SE']:
   *         print(f"Can't register {index}")
    else:
        for index in it_courses['CS']:
            print(f"Can't register {index}")

register_courses(it_courses, 'CS')
```

***2:***

```
def register_courses(it_courses, dep_acronym):
    for key in it_courses:
        if key != dep_acronym:
            for i in it_courses[key]:
              print("Can't register ",i)
```

**Is there different in complexity and is that what i needed in clean code?**

Comment: I wouldn't worry about time complexity unless you can anticipate that you will have enough classes to process that the time efficiency of your code makes any significant difference to the run time.  With your current code, the `print` statements will contribute most of the execution time.  So as long as you want to print the same information in either case, the two methods should be indistinguishable from an execution time perspective.  You should be more interested in readability and maintainability, and #2 is by far the better choice in terms of those concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no complexity difference. Say we have 10 departments. Then you will have 10 if statements in #1, versus 10 things to loop over in the outer loop of #2. In the inner loop, you will still have to print the same number of things for both #1 and #2.

#2 is *much* cleaner, as #1 will become very large (lots of if statements) once you add more departments.

Comment: Big O is the same because only 2 keys. If you need to extend to more departments, the time complexity will remain the same. Time complexity *is* big O for all intents and purposes here.

Answer (score -1):

#1 has a linear time or O(n) complexity while #2 also has a linear complexity but with a slightly higher coefficient that will be O(n+2)//estimated.

Comment: They are both supposed to print the classes that are not in the department. So I think they have the same outcome. And in that case, they will also have the same complexity, as a function of the number of departments and the number of courses.